# Multiple persistence unit in persistence.xml file with JPA 2.1

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to deploy an application that connects to Oracle Database and MySQL. I am using JPA 2.1, Hibernate 4.3.7, Spring, Spring Data and WildFly 8.2 but I am getting some errors when deploying the application. Eclipse shows error. He says that I cannot use more than one persistence unit. I was confused because I found some articles on the web showing files with more than one persistence unit. [Like this one](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/hibernate-jpa/jpa-configuration/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-persistencexml).

First of all my `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="authwsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/datasource/authwsds</jta-data-source>

        ..My MySQL mapping classes...

        <properties>
            <!-- MySQL -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/authwsEMF" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="antaresPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/datasource/antaresds</jta-data-source>

        ...My Oracle mapping classes...

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/antaresEMF" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I made change on `jboss-web.xml` too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
                               http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">

    <context-root>/authws</context-root>

    <persistence-context-ref id="autenticacaoCtx">
        <persistence-context-ref-name>auth_ws/authEMF</persistence-context-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>authwsPU</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-context-ref>

    <persistence-context-ref id="antaresCtx">
        <persistence-context-ref-name>auth_ws/antaresEMF</persistence-context-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>antaresPU</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-context-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

And the errors. Eclipse, warned me, but I ignored.:

```
Multiple persistence units defined - only the first persistence unit will be recognized
```

Then I deployed and WildFly shows this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011470: Persistence unitName was not specified and there are 2 persistence unit definitions in application deployment deployment "authws.war".  Either change the application deployment to have only one persistence unit definition or specify the unitName for each reference to a persistence unit.
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.ambiguousPUError(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.findWithinDeployment(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.findPersistenceUnitSupplier(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.resolvePersistenceUnitSupplier(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.getPersistenceUnit(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:372)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.getBindingSource(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:296)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.processMethod(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:206)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.processPersistenceAnnotations(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.deploy(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

**UPDATE**

I am updating the question with more details. First, the file where I create the EntityManagersFactory for Spring Data:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/poEMF" id="poEntityManagerFactory" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.po.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="poEntityManagerFactory"  />

<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/antaresEMF" id="antaresEntityManagerFactory" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.antares.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="antaresEntityManagerFactory" />
```

Reading more about this online, I saw that the problem can be specification of the annotation `@PersistenceUnit` where I have to specify the `unitName` like `@PersistenceUnit(unitName="defaultPersistenceUnit")`. **But, how I do this if I am using Spring Data?**

Comment: hi @Ricardo, did you solve this problem. We are getting NameNotFoundException when try to get in spring. This is happening in multiple persistence units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can use @EnableJpaRepositories in your @Configuration files (if you are using Bean Configuration) like this:

One configuration file with:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @EnableJpaRepositories(
       basePackages = {"com.yourpackage.xxxx"},
       entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory1",
       transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
       public class FirstPersistenceContextConfig {}
....
```

And a second configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
       basePackages = {"com.yourpackage.yyyy"},
       entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory2",
       transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
       public class SecondPersistenceContextConfig {}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've solved your problem.

If you're using a XML configuration, try this:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="[repository]" 
    entity-manager-factory-ref="mysqlManager" transaction-manager-ref="mysqlTransaction"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="[repository]" 
    entity-manager-factory-ref="oracleManager" transaction-manager-ref="oracleTransaction"/>

<bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <!-- MySQL Configuration Connection -->
</bean>        

<bean id="mysqlTransaction" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="mysqlManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="mysqlManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">        
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mysqlPU" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="lh.ast.model" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>                
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>     
</bean>

<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <!-- Oracle Configuration Connection -->
</bean>

<bean id="oracleTransaction" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="oracleManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="oracleManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">        
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="oraclePU" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="[your entity package]" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>    
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>            
        </props>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Comment: Perhaps, if your code were commented for explain the use of two EntityManagerFactory and each TransactionManager, I would have gave points but i consider the answer is poor